# Using modifier on view function works locally, but fails on Ropsten

Tags: solidity, web3js, ropsten, mapping, modifiers

Hey I'm trying to make it inconvenient to view stored data in a contract, but it seems that the function is returning null values when I add a modifier. 
The modifier makes sure someone is approved before viewing the data using the getter. 
I've made sure the data is getting stored and the person is indeed approved.

Example:

```
struct StoredData { 
    int a; 
    uint256 b;
    uint256 c; 
    uint256 d; 
    uint256 e; 
    uint256 f; 
}

mapping (uint256 => StoredData) private data; 
mapping (address => bool) public allowedToView; 

modifier onlyViewer() { 
  require(allowedToView[msg.sender]); 
  _; 
}


function getStoredData(_index) onlyViewer constant public 
returns (int, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) 
   { 
     return (data[_index].a, data[_index].b, data[_index].c, data[_index].d, data[_index].e, data[_index].f); 
   }
```

Comment: The storage of your contract is public - even the "private" data storage variable; anyone can view the contents of a Smart Contract directly - without going through your getStoredData function. What you are trying to achieve really does only make it marginally more inconvenient.

Comment: I know. It's more for demo purposes. While were on the topic though, can you explain the process of viewing private data? How much more inconvenient is it?

Comment: [This is a great article](https://medium.com/aigang-network/how-to-read-ethereum-contract-storage-44252c8af925) explaining how to view data in a Smart Contract's storage - examples coving a range of datatypes

Comment: Sweet that is a great article. For the nature of this Dapp, this is enough inconvenience to justify the cost (very minimal and doesn't truly need to be private). Thanks for the link!